# Comparing elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logic

given, `li=[6,1,5,1,3,1]`
Now I want to check if an element of the list is greater than or equal to all the succeeding elements. 
So my required answer should be 
6,5,3,1
Please help.
Requesting the answer to be 'non-pythonic' lol.
I have tried this,

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    for j in li[i+1:]:
        if li[i]>j:
            print(li[i])
            break
```

It works partly, but fails for scenarios like [6,1,5,1,3,1,1] where i also want 1 as the answer

Comment: Isn't your answer be: 6
5
3
1?
because 6 is also the greatest to succeeding elements.

Comment: You can use list slicing to get a list of all the elements past a given index, and you can use `max()` to get the greatest value in a list.

Comment: @PratibhaGupta yes thank you, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient approach with a time complexity of *O(n)* would be to iterate through the list in reverse order instead, so the problem can become simply to determine if the current item is greater than or equal to the last item in the output, and then reverse the output again in the end:

```
output = [li.pop()]
for i in reversed(li):
    if i >= output[-1]:
        output.append(i)
output = output[::-1]
```

`output` becomes:

```
[6, 5, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
li = [6, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1]

result = []

for i in li:
    index = li.index(i)
    if index is 0:
        continue
    if index is len(li) - 1:
        continue
    if li[index - 1] <= i => li[index + 1]:
        result.append(i)
 print(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for [6,1,5,1,3,1,1] where the answer should be 6,5,3,1 it's showing only 5,3

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have seen you have edited to add some code that proved you have tried, thanks for doing that, we like to see more of that !

However your attempt has a [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of O(N^2), because you run a for loop of length(li) with a nested loop of length(li) - 1, which means *for every character in li, you have to go through `len(li)` times*, which is slow.

This is a "non-pythonic" way to do it, it only loops through li once, and fairly simple:

```
li=[6,1,5,1,3,1,1]
prev = li[0] # first element
output = []
for i in range(1, len(li)):
    if(prev >= li[i]):
        output.append(prev)
    prev = li[i]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[6, 5, 3, 1]
```

**NOTE**: After some more reading of your question, I realised I may have misinterpreted your question.

> Now I want to check if an element of the list is greater than or equal to all the succeeding elements.

I didn't notice that "all", and I apologise for that.

I can do this the "pythonic-ish" way, by using list slicing:

```
li=[6,1,5,1,3,1,1]
output=[]
for i in range(0, len(li)):
    if(len(li[i+1:]) == 0): #if last element
        break # you can choose to count this in or not
    if(li[i] >= max(li[i+1:])): # if current element larger or equals max of ALL successive elements
        output.append(li[i])

print(output)
```

Output (still the same):

```
[6, 5, 3, 1]
```

Now in this solution, the time complexity will be O(N^2), because max is a O(N) function, and it is being called N times, resulting in O(N*N) = O(N^2) time

Comment: @suhaasbadada No worries :) By the way, I have added some remarks on your attempt, it could help you improve your programming skills !

Comment: Does not work for cases like `li = [6, 1, 5, 1, 3, 7, 1]`, where the output should be `[7, 1]`.

Comment: @suhaasbadada and blhsing, it seems that I have misinterpreted the question, I have added the solution for the interpretation, I'm truly sorry for that mistake

Comment: @blhsing Should ```1``` be included though? As it does not have any successive element(s) anymore, though it could be easily changed in my added solution

Comment: The updated solution calls `max` in a loop, resulting in a time complexity of *O(n ^ 2)*.

Comment: @blhsing Whoops, lemme add that, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

This should return you expected result:

```
li=[6,1,5,1,3,1]
filtered = []
for i, val in enumerate(li):
 for r in li[i+1:]:
  if val > r:
   continue
  else:
   break
 else:
  filtered.append(val)
print(filtered)
```